# How can I group multiple rows of the same variable with different outputs in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am doing a study on the relationship between GDP and number of medals won at the Olympic games. I have multiple years of the same country with different GDPs and medal counts. I'm looking to summarize an entire country. I think I could use dplyr, but am having trouble getting started. Is there a different package that may be more suitable for this? Below is the code I have done so far, but this will take a long time since I have over 100 countries to do this for.

```
  filter(country == "Argentina") %>%
  select(year, country, total, GDP)
str(master)
reg1 <- lm(total ~ GDP, data = Argentina)
summary(reg1)
```

Comment: Have a look here for applying `lm` to many subgroups using `dplyr` and `broom`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

Comment: how much data (rows and column) is in each country? if its moderate, it won't take that long?

Comment: you can nest by each country and then add a column that does a linear model for each country